# Windows zip error: Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination file could not be created

Tags: windows, zip, archiving

I have a strange error in Windows 7 when I want to execute/open a file inside ZIP archive.

I have two files:

```
File1.dwg
File2.dwg
```

The archive **is not corrupted** ( I checked with 7zip utility )

[image]

When I double click on the any file inside ZIP (I opened ZIP with Windows Explorer), the error occured:

[image]

Ok. If I open zip file with **7-zip** or **WinRAR** every file could be opened(executed) without error and the AutoCAD is opened to see the dwg content.

Why in Windows ZIP ?

What points have I to see to manage/remove this error ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

If I click `Extract all` from Windows ZIP, the error occured as unspecified error:

[image]

Comment: Where is the ZIP file? On your hard drive, on a CD or USB flash drive?

Comment: On the hard-drive. No SSD, USB or CD/DVD.

Comment: Please open the ZIP file as administrator (hold control+shift when double clicking to open the zip file) and then try.

Comment: And try to disable all AV/Firewall (if confident to do so). Some times the error code is based upon lack of resources (which can be caused by firewall/av)

Comment: And lastly, re-install WinZip

Comment: I have not WinZip, is about just Windows native ZIP reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Windows is having a hard time creating the temporary file for you to view (it extracts it into temp when you double-click it, then opens it for viewing). Perhaps clear out your temp folder (there are tools online for this) and try again to view the files.

Out of interest, though, can you extract the files normally (via the "Extract all" command) specifying a path (which obviously isn't temp)?

Comment: See my updated question. Appears an error. It's a stupid error when other tools works perfectly.

Comment: Where did you try to extract to? Where's the zip file at?

Comment: Anywhere on the disk (Desktop, partition D, in temp folder)

Comment: The problem is the generated zip by my application written in C# using ZipForge. Must be set CompressionMode to a value (it's a byte) and will works fine.

Comment: I thought was the windows fault but is my fault as programmer.

Comment: I wouldn't be so hard on yourself - it sounds like a limitation in the implementation of Zip that Windows includes at the same time, since 7-zip and WinRar had no trouble with it. Another step of progress in your debug! Be happy!

Answer (score 13):

That error message can be a bit misleading.  If the file in the zip you are opening is password protected that could be the problem. Windows can't handle AES-256 encryption which comes up as the default in the 7zip UI when password protecting files through the UI.  If you change to ZipCrypto, then windows should be able to read it after prompting for the password.

Comment: Or if you use 7zip like the sender used ;-P

Comment: I ran into the same problem today trying to open a AES-256 encrypted zip. Had to use another file openner(WinZip, since both WinRar and 7zip apparently doesn't have the "open with" option). Out of curiosity, do you have any recommendation of any other software that can open AES-256 encrypted zips, and has the "open with" option?